# Append prepared string to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the main navigation there are some links including a#estimate

```
mainNav = document.getElementById('mainNavigation');
subNav = document.getElementById('subNavigation');
```

This is subnavigation for a#estimate

```
estimateSubNav = '<li><a href="?s=estimate&p=create">Create new</a></li>';
```

All I need to do is check what ID has current link...

```
currSectionId = $(mainNav).find('a.current').attr('id');
```

...and on this basis append to unordered subnav list prepared string

```
$(subNav).append(currSectionId+'SubNav');
```

So in "the estimate" case, the sub navigation should look like

```
<ul id="subNavigation">
  <li><a href="?s=estimate&p=create">Create new</a></li>
</ul>
```

At this moment it shows me just estimateSubNav, like you can read it

```
<ul id="subNavigation">
  estimateSubNav
</ul>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/8sHnC/3/

Comment: Could you *show* us your (relevant) HTML, describing it for us is prone to misrepresentation, ambiguity and misunderstanding.

Comment: @David Thomas What exactly? Link with ID "estimate"?

Comment: Given that you appear to be selecting other elements by their `id` and doing something with them, no. *All* of the relevant HTML.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us?

Comment: You can update in this http://jsfiddle.net/2D6Hn/ and show us what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is what you are trying to do

```
var mainNav = document.getElementById('mainNavigation');
var subNav = document.getElementById('subNavigation');

var estimateSubNav = '<li><a href="?s=estimate&p=create">Create new</a></li>';

var currSectionElement = $(mainNav).find('a.current')[0];        

var newElement=$(currSectionElement).clone().attr("id",currSectionElement.id+"subNav");

$(subNav).append(newElement);
```

Based on your Fiddle, [**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sHnC/1/)

Comment: thank you very much for your response. Actually, I need to edit your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8sHnC/

Comment: I hope you can see the same as I do in the fiddle, but the result is same as on the start...:/ Why the result shows "estimateSubNav" instead of prepared estimateSubNav variable?

Comment: @falcon, really not getting your problem

Comment: And I'm so sorry about that because of wasting your time :/

Comment: I just need to check on window load what ID has a.current and then use that ID as the part of appended variable...

Comment: Anyway, +1, +10 if only I could, for your help.

Comment: @falcon, instead of doing it in window.load, better do in in `$(documentation).ready(...)`. Whatever js code i wrote in the fiddle is automatically wrapped by document.ready and executes for us. In our application, we need to put our execution on document.ready. Read [this](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) for more information :)

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will solve your problem

```
var li = $("<li/>").attr("href","?s="+currSectionId+"&p=create");
$(subNav).append(li);
```

Comment: Hi Jeetendra. At first, thank you for your answer. My goal is use an ID as the part of appended variable. So if the a.current has ID "l" then I need to .append(l+"i") according to your pattern.